# Python: Differences in string handling between Windows and Linux

Tags: python-3.x

I have this little Python 3 code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

emailTextHTML = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><title>Wöchentliche Ticketbenachrichtigung</title></head><body><p>Hallo ...,</p></body></html>'
msg = MIMEText(emailTextHTML, 'html')
msg['Subject'] = 'TEST Wöchentliche Ticketbenachrichtigung TEST'
msg['From'] = 'reminderscript@blubb.de'
msg['To'] = 'asdf@blubb.de'
s = smtplib.SMTP('192.168.115.99')
#try:
s.send_message(msg)
#except:
print(msg)
s.quit()
```

Now the problem is that it runs fine with Python 3.3.2 on Windows 7 x64, but it fails with Python 3.2.3 on Debian Linux x64. I get this error when using the last setup:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 13, in <module>
    s.send_message(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/smtplib.py", line 812, in send_message
    g.flatten(msg_copy, linesep='\r\n')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/email/generator.py", line 91, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/email/generator.py", line 137, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/email/generator.py", line 163, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/email/generator.py", line 398, in _handle_text
    super(BytesGenerator,self)._handle_text(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/email/generator.py", line 201, in _handle_text
    self.write(payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/email/generator.py", line 357, in write
    self._fp.write(s.encode('ascii', 'surrogateescape'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 188: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The german umlaut in the string is causing this. But why does it succeed on Windows and fail on Linux? What can I do to make the code compatible with both environments? Console encoding doesn't seem to be of relevance here, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to change line 7 from

```
msg = MIMEText(emailTextHTML, 'html')
```

to

```
msg = MIMEText(emailTextHTML, 'html', 'utf-8')
```

Now it works in both environments.

Python bugs [7304](http://bugs.python.org/issue7304) and [14380](http://bugs.python.org/issue14380) seems to be related to this. So my problem was more of a Python 3.2 to 3.3 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you write in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18573582/1346705. Python 3.3 contains in `MIMEText.__init__()`

```
    # If no _charset was specified, check to see if there are non-ascii
    # characters present. If not, use 'us-ascii', otherwise use utf-8.
    # XXX: This can be removed once #7304 is fixed.
    if _charset is None:
        try:
            _text.encode('us-ascii')
            _charset = 'us-ascii'
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            _charset = 'utf-8'
```

Python 3.2 does not contain that specific code.

The reason why the charset should be specified (explicitly or fixed like in 3.3 or somehow) is that sometimes `open` and the like functions use the OS prefered encoding. It may complicate the things. Also, the `print` in your case may cause similar problems as a console usually does not use Unicode.